# what cause this can't continue on the process on the other elements?

Tags: c, arrays

```
char passage[5000][20];

int para_count(p)
{
    int i=0,n,para_sentence=0,para_no=7,para[10];
    for(n=1;n<=para_no;n++)
    {
        while (passage[i][0]!='\n')
        {
            if (punc_check(i,strlen(passage+i)-1)==1)
            {
                para_sentence++;
            } 
            i++;
        }
        para[n] = para_sentence;
        para_sentence=0;
    }
    return para[p];
}
```

This is my function to count no. of sentences in a paragraph of a passage. It will keep on counting sentence until `\n`.
It will store the number of sentence counted previously into an array: `para`. The number of sentences in the nth paragraph will be stored in `para[n]`.

But it only count the first paragraph (the value is returned successfully), from `para[2]` onward they are all `0`, I suppose `para_sentence` will be keep updating, right?

my example text:

> I am most blessed to born in this era of computing. When I was in primary school, I first came across computer through computer games called “Maple Story”,where  I showed up as adventurer travelling through a virtual world and killing monsters in the game. I was fascinated by the colourful graphics and amazing adventures, wondering how this could be done which has opened up my curiosity in the computing world. I was totally amazed by it when I first used a computer, it was very novel to me at that time.  As I play more, I started to encounter malfunctioning which pushed me to seek for solutions, this is how I learnt more about the functioning of computers. This attracted me to explore more in this field, I started to go beyond just playing games. Besides gaming I am also deeply attracted by the internet world, I truly experience “information at my fingertips”, like a magician with a magic wand.  As I continued my exploration on computer technology, the foundation of my passion and skills on computer grew gradually, I got to understand how incredible computing technology was, making it as my interest. Not only that, I started considering computer and technology as my future study or even lifelong career. I promised myself that I will definitely pursue my career in the computing world.
>
> I am deeply impressed by your University. Since its foundation a century ago, HK University has been the top Asian University, many leaders from all walks of life completed their higher education in this prestigious University. I am attracted to the computing course offered by the department of Economics due to its  good mix of computer technologies and applications in economics. Many professors in the department are world famous scholars with significant contribution in the field of economics, as well as computing. I deeply desire to join your department and be part of the group.
>
> I have pursued a lot of computing related activities in addition to an academic subject. I took up a part time job as a computer advisor in a graphics design company managed by my uncle. He does not have too much knowledge on computer so I help him to set up his Macbook, like installing different softwares. I also help him out with the problems he encountered related to computers, from minor problems like how to save file to cloud drive, to major problems like Internet failure. Despite just solving the issues, I also give recommendations on how to make his job easier and avoid the problems again. For instance, I suggested and helped him to update his router, including the setup of it. Other than these, I deliver him the latest technology development as well, explaining things like AI, and esports. Through this experience, I understood more about the application of technology and what exactly working environment is and developed my communicative skills.
>
> I have also exposed myself to computer hardware as well . Two years ago, I acquired a desktop computer for myself, but instead of buying an off the shelf product, I bought parts and assembled the machine by myself. My ICT teacher was very helpful and guided me through the whole process of assembly step by step, I gained a lot of hardware knowledge that I can hardly learn at class, like how to look at the specification of CPU and motherboard. It was really a great experience for me to get in touch with and know more about hardwares.
>
> I like computing very much and I truly want to develop my career in this field. Not only your university offers the most suitable course for me, but also the favorable learning environment. I believe that I shall enjoy studying the course very much in your university and open up my potentials.

output:

```
n       para[n]
1       10
2       0
3       0
4       0
5       0
```

Comment: please add an example of input text, the expected result, and the actual result (obtained with your program).

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use a debugger. Also your question is missing [mcve].

Comment: The inner loop only depends on `i`, not on `n`. What will happen when you've encountered the first newline?

Comment: In C array indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Retired Ninja it's not solving the problem sadly :(